# Python Email TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

In a very simple example of sending an email:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

message = MIMEText("test message")
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail("example@example.com", ["example@example.com"], message)
```

I get the following error from the last line of my code:

TypeError: expected string or buffer

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass `message.as_string()` to sendmail.

In the example give, it would look like this:

```
s.sendmail("example@example.com", ["example@example.com"], message.as_string())
```